# WCF Simultaneous Update of Objects in callback

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

Is it possible to update multiple objects in one callback channel simultaneously properly? I am developing a software right now and I have put multiple objects under one callback channel. These objects should be accessed by my client simultaneously. Problem is, there was only one object that is being updated, and the others were not.

Comment: Add some of the code, so we can understand the problem?

Answer (score 1):

technically speaking when you are using WCF you will try to have a certain design like SOA, so instead of calling WCF services multiple times for a single operation,  is better if you think of it like a holistic method, like AddNewOrder, and your parameter for that method will be a complex object like the following class:

```
public class AddNewOrderRequest{
    public List<Products> Products
    public Person BuyerOfOrder
    //etc etc
    //many other elements that need to be persisted
}
```

and then calling your WCF service, do it like this:

```
AddNewOrderResponse response = MyOrderService.AddOrder(AddNewOrderRequest request);
```

I hope, it helps.

Comment: Thank you @JorgeAlvarado for the insight. However, I think, what you are suggesting is a request-reply scenario. What I am implementing right now is duplex. However, if I got your suggestion correctly, I will try creating an object that spearheads all of my existing objects.